# Add to home screen button on iOS showing "app" instead of my app name

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, ionic4

I've been working on an app built in Ionic 4, and have been experimenting with turning it into a PWA. Thish is working well so far, ecept for one thing: on iOS, when I hit "add to home screen", it's showing the wrong app name:

(I don't have enough reputation to post images, so have a link: https://i.redd.it/migojjki4gs21.png)

Here, it's showing "app" instead of "Allergyst", my app name, which it should. I've set the names in manifest.json and as a  tag, and also with `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="allergyst">`. I assume it's a problem with iOS's cobbled-together support for progressive web apps.

Does anybody have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem after digging into the `www` folder in my Ionic app. It seems that, for some reason, Ionic has been resetting my `"name"` and `"short-name"` entries in the `manifest.json` to `app` everytime I build.

This bug seems to be localized to this project in general. I created a new Ionic project to be sure and couldn't recreate the problem, so if anyone else is experiencing this issue, I recommend copying all your essential files over to a brand-new project and starting from there.